# How can I prove $f(x) = \frac32 x − \frac23$ is surjective?

Tags: analysis

So I'm trying to prove the function $f(x) = \frac32 x − \frac23$ is bijective (injective and surjective)...

For injection I can easily write $\frac32x - \frac23 = \frac32y - \frac23$; that gives me $x=y$ so it's injective.

So the one more step to prove is to show function is surjective. I can say $f(x)=y$ which gives me $\frac32 x - \frac23 = y$ or $\frac{9x - 4}{6} = y$,
which finally gives me $x = \frac{6y+4}{9}$.

But there is a problem when I plug $x$ in function $\frac32 x - \frac23$ I can't get that $y$ value... Basically I get $\frac32 (6y + 4)\frac19 - \frac23 \implies 6y + \frac23 - \frac23$ which is $6y$ but I need $y$? I saw on Wolfram that this function must be surjective but I don't know how to prove it. Can anyone help me with that. And almost forgot to mention $f :\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: $(3/2)\times 6y/9 = y$. Check your algebra.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial.  Do you mean $\dfrac3{2x}-\dfrac23$ or $\dfrac32x-\dfrac23$?

Comment: @fleablood to show injective, you show that $f(x)=f(y)$ forces $x=y$. Here, the equation $f(x)=f(y)$ is $\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{3}{2}y-\frac{2}{3}$. Doing basic algebra reduces the equation to $x=y$.

Comment: "which is 6y but I need y??"  That can only happen if you made an arithmetic error.  Check your math: $\frac 32\frac {6y+4}9-\frac 23=\frac {18y+12}{18}-\frac 23=\frac {18y + 12- 12}{18} = \frac {18y}{18}=y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is surjective, you just made a small computational error.

\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{2} \frac{6y+4}{9} - \frac{2}{3} &= \frac{6y+4}{6} - \frac{2}{3}\\
&= y + \frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\\
&= y.
\end{align*}

Comment: Did you mean $y\color{red}+\dfrac23$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I'll edit now, thanks!

Comment: Ohhh this is just embarrasing. But yeah u're right so ty :)